# How to use `in` expression in Mapbox GL map.setFilter

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to filter a geoJson layer (called "destinations") based on a set of conditions. My "destinations" layer has a property called `uniqueID` of type string, which most of the time only has one numeric ID, but sometime has more than one. I would like to filter this layer (using `map.setFilter`) based on an array of IDs. The filter should do something like this: if any of the `uniqueID` values in the "destination" layer are found in the array of IDs, then filter that feature out.

Here is an snippet of my "destinations" layer:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "destinationLon": -74.20716879, "destinationLat": 40.69097357, "uniqueID": "2029" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.20716879, 40.69097357 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "destinationLon": -74.20670807, "destinationLat": 40.69137214, "uniqueID": "984,985" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.20670807, 40.69137214 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "destinationLon": -74.20651489, "destinationLat": 40.71887889, "uniqueID": "1393" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -74.20651489, 40.71887889 ] } }
```

And here is a sample of the array of IDs I might use: `[2000, 984, 1393]`

I have tried using a filter using the `in` expression (documentation [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#in)) like this:

```js
let thisFilter = ["any"].concat(uniqueIDs.map(id => ["in", id, ["get", "uniqueID"]]));
map.setFilter("destinations", thisFilter);
```

But I keep on getting this error message:

```
Error: "layers.destinations.filter[0][2]: string, number, or boolean expected, array found"
```

However, the documentation states the following:

```
["in",
    keyword: InputType (boolean, string, or number),
    input: InputType (array or string)
]: boolean
```

The third argument in the expression is supposed to be an array. Why then am I getting that error?

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think your error has nothing to do with `in`. You could discover this by simplifying your expression, and separating out the `any` from the individual `in` parts.

Your error is that `any` takes a variable number of parameters:

```
['any', ['in', ...], ['in', ...]]
```

Whereas you are passing in an array:

```
['any', [['in', ...], ['in', ...]]]
```

I would rewrite your expression like this:

```js
let thisFilter = ["any", ...uniqueIDs.map(id => ["in", id, ["get", "uniqueID"]])];
```